# Functions are not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I've made an `include.js` file where I've put all general functions in. Before that functions were in the file itself.

I'm getting an error from the Chrome console saying that `changeColor()` is not defined.

I didn't want it to get messy here, so I've paste some of my post on PasteBin.

```
if(username.val() == '')
{
    changeColor('#inputname');
    exclamation('#inputname');
    $.notify("U hebt geen gebruikersnaam opgegeven", "error");
    return false;
}
```

So `changeColor()` is undefined, same goes for `exclamation()`. Now comes the Pastebin part: http://pastebin.com/5bbPuT4e

As you can see I have a `header.php` file where I include all JS files that are necessary for my entire website. In the `include.js` file the functions are made, and in the `aanmelden.js` file the functions are called. In my point of view I can't look clear anymore so I don't really know what I did wrong.

Comment: `changeColor()` and `exclamation()` are being declared locally in your `document...ready` function. They don't exist outside that function. While it's good to wait to *call* functions in `document..ready`, you don't necessarily want to *define* functions in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the document.ready in the include.js. This creates scope, so changeColor and exclamation only live inside the wrapping function. include.js should be:

```
 function changeColor(elem) {
            $(elem).css({
                    "border-radius": "5px",
                    "font-weight":   "bolder",
                    "border":        "1px solid red"
            });
  }           
  function exclamation(elem) {                   
          $(elem).notify(
                "-",
                        { position:"right" }
          );
  }
```

Notice how there is no longer document.ready.

Some info on function scope in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, I will accept your answer in 5 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you could extend the jQuery prototype to use those method in a more "jQuery way":

```
$.fn.extend({

  changeColor: function() {    
    return this.each(function() {
      this.css({
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "font-weight":   "bolder",
        "border":        "1px solid red"
      });
    });
  },

  exclamation: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.notify("-", {position:"right"});
    });
  }

});

// Use the newly created methods like this:
$('#inputname').changeColor();
$('#inputname').exclamation();
```

This way you shouldn't be worried about the scope where you define the functions.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew there was a function out there like this. Can be useful in time! :-)